# kill process username variable ? (Windows)

Tags: windows, process, cmd, taskkill

Is there a way to kill a process only from the current user with variable %username% ?

Let's say I'm logged in so I want to kill the process cmd.exe only in my session but I need this with a variable.

I tried this

> taskkill /F /FI "%username%" /IM cmd.exe

but this doesn't work.

Comment: please try to run `taskkill /F /FI "USERNAME eq %username%" /IM cmd.exe`

Comment: OK, so I am posting this as an answer so the question is not left unanswered.

Answer (score 5):

According to `taskkill /?` you have to provide the parameter name in the filter. To filter by username, you have to run

```
taskkill /F /FI "USERNAME eq %username%" /IM cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure the user you are running taskkill with has enough privilages to kill the process of another user.